# python - json with multiple object to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing, multiple-columns

I receive files (json) from time to time from AWS sns. Some of them contain only 1 object, some other have several objects.

I am trying to run a python script to extract a couple of columns as example but I get multiple errors due to this several objects or the format of the file. Ideally I want to get all the data into columns, specially the ones contained inside the "Message" section. (I.e. eventType, from, to, bcc, messageId, timestamp, etc.

Can anybody help?
Thanks

**script:**

```
data = []
for line in open(folder + file, 'r', encoding='utf-8'):
    data.append(json.loads(line))
    pd.json_normalize(data)

    #df = pd.DataFrame(((d['Message']) for d in data), columns=['Message'])
    df = pd.DataFrame([(
         data[0]['Timestamp'],
         data[0]['Subject'],
         data[0]['Message']['eventType'])
     ], columns=['Timestamp', 'Subject', 'eventType'])

    df.to_csv(folder + 'testOutput.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    print(df)
```

**Example file with multiple objects:**

```
{"Type":"Notification","MessageId":"0579da9d-671f-547f-879a-8151d6048","TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:region:123456789:SES-notification-s","Subject":"Event Notification","Message":"{\"eventType\":\"Click\",\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-10-21T14:39:47.003Z\",\"source\":\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\",\"sendingAccountId\":\"123456789\",\"messageId\":\"01000183fafc5f3b-4f5f3dc2-281a-472a-85-915f85289858-000000\",\"destination\":[\"toemail@email.com\",\"bccemail@email.com\"],\"headersTruncated\":false,\"headers\":[{\"name\":\"Content-Type\",\"value\":\"multipart/mixed; boundary=\\\"===============4453571503606487627==\\\"\"},{\"name\":\"MIME-Version\",\"value\":\"1.0\"},{\"name\":\"Subject\",\"value\":\"Email tracking test\"},{\"name\":\"From\",\"value\":\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\"},{\"name\":\"To\",\"value\":\"toemail@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Bcc\",\"value\":\"bccemail@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Message-ID\",\"value\":\"null\"}],\"commonHeaders\":{\"from\":[\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\"],\"to\":[\"toemail@email.com\"],\"bcc\":[\"bccemail@email.com\"],\"messageId\":\"010001fafc5f33b-4f53dc2-281a-472a-8f65-915f889858-000000\",\"subject\":\"Email tracking test\"},\"tags\":{\"ses:operation\":[\"SendRawEmail\"],\"ses:configuration-set\":[\"ses-email-tracking\"],\"ses:source-ip\":[\"12.12.123.123\"],\"ses:from-domain\":[\"domain.dev\"],\"ses:caller-identity\":[\"caller_identity\"]}},\"click\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-10-21T14:40:55.000Z\",\"ipAddress\":\"66.66.666.666\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\",\"link\":\"https://website.com\",\"linkTags\":null}}\n","Timestamp":"2022-10-21T14:40:55.066Z","UnsubscribeURL":"unsubscribeLink"}
{"Type":"Notification","MessageId":"03758739-75a9-5462-8361-dcf5c410e015","TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:region:123456789:SES-notification-s","Subject":"Event Notification","Message":"{\"eventType\":\"ClickNum2\",\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-10-21T14:39:47.003Z\",\"source\":\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\",\"sendingAccountId\":\"123456789\",\"messageId\":\"01000183fafc5f3b-4f5f3dc2-281a-472a-85-915f85289858-000000\",\"destination\":[\"toemail2@email.com\",\"bccemail2@email.com\"],\"headersTruncated\":false,\"headers\":[{\"name\":\"Content-Type\",\"value\":\"multipart/mixed; boundary=\\\"===============4453571503606487627==\\\"\"},{\"name\":\"MIME-Version\",\"value\":\"1.0\"},{\"name\":\"Subject\",\"value\":\"Email tracking test\"},{\"name\":\"From\",\"value\":\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\"},{\"name\":\"To\",\"value\":\"toemail2@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Bcc\",\"value\":\"bccemail2@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Message-ID\",\"value\":\"null\"}],\"commonHeaders\":{\"from\":[\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\"],\"to\":[\"toemail2@email.com\"],\"bcc\":[\"bccemail2@email.com\"],\"messageId\":\"010001fafc5f33b-4f53dc2-281a-472a-8f65-915f889858-000000\",\"subject\":\"Email tracking test\"},\"tags\":{\"ses:operation\":[\"SendRawEmail\"],\"ses:configuration-set\":[\"ses-email-tracking\"],\"ses:source-ip\":[\"12.12.123.123\"],\"ses:from-domain\":[\"domain.dev\"],\"ses:caller-identity\":[\"caller_identity\"]}},\"click2\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-10-21T15:45:50.000Z\",\"ipAddress\":\"55.55.555.555\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\",\"link\":\"https://website.com\",\"linkTags\":null}}\n","Timestamp":"2022-10-21T15:50:50.066Z","UnsubscribeURL":"unsubscribeLink"}
{"Type":"Notification","MessageId":"03758739-75a9-5462-8361-dcf5c410e015","TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:region:123456789:SES-notification-s","Subject":"Event Notification","Message":"{\"eventType\":\"ClickNum3\",\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-10-21T14:39:47.003Z\",\"source\":\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\",\"sendingAccountId\":\"123456789\",\"messageId\":\"01000183fafc5f3b-4f5f3dc2-281a-472a-85-915f85289858-000000\",\"destination\":[\"toemail3@email.com\",\"bccemail3@email.com\"],\"headersTruncated\":false,\"headers\":[{\"name\":\"Content-Type\",\"value\":\"multipart/mixed; boundary=\\\"===============4453571503606487627==\\\"\"},{\"name\":\"MIME-Version\",\"value\":\"1.0\"},{\"name\":\"Subject\",\"value\":\"Email tracking test\"},{\"name\":\"From\",\"value\":\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\"},{\"name\":\"To\",\"value\":\"toemail3@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Bcc\",\"value\":\"bccemail3@email.com\"},{\"name\":\"Message-ID\",\"value\":\"null\"}],\"commonHeaders\":{\"from\":[\"tester <fromemail@email.com>\"],\"to\":[\"toemail3@email.com\"],\"bcc\":[\"bccemail3@email.com\"],\"messageId\":\"010001fafc5f33b-4f53dc2-281a-472a-8f65-915f889858-000000\",\"subject\":\"Email tracking test\"},\"tags\":{\"ses:operation\":[\"SendRawEmail\"],\"ses:configuration-set\":[\"ses-email-tracking\"],\"ses:source-ip\":[\"12.12.123.123\"],\"ses:from-domain\":[\"domain.dev\"],\"ses:caller-identity\":[\"caller_identity\"]}},\"click3\":{\"timestamp\":\"2022-10-21T16:50:50.000Z\",\"ipAddress\":\"44.44.444.444\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\",\"link\":\"https://website.com\",\"linkTags\":null}}\n","Timestamp":"2022-10-21T16:50:50.066Z","UnsubscribeURL":"unsubscribeLink"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to include all fields from json to csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df=pd.read_json('test.json',lines=True)
newdf=[]
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    data=json.loads(row['Message'])
    row['timestamp']=data['mail']['timestamp']
    row['eventType']=data['eventType']
    newdf.append(row)
df=pd.DataFrame(newdf)
df.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! This one is a shorter way to move it. However, this does not split by column the content in the column "Message", which is pretty big. Would you know how to add that into new columns in the csv? Thanks

Comment: try now this may work

Answer (score 0):

how about parse whole input:

```py
import fileinput
import json

import pandas as pd


def parse_input(filename):

    rows = (l for l in fileinput.input(filename))
    parsed_1 = [json.loads(row) for row in rows]
    for row in parsed_1:
        row['Message'] = json.loads(row['Message'])

    return parsed_1


input = parse_input('input.txt')
```

Then

```
df = pd.json_normalize(input)
```

and choose the desired columns?

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
           Type                             MessageId  ...  Message.click3.link Message.click3.linkTags
0  Notification     0579da9d-671f-547f-879a-8151d6048  ...                  NaN                     NaN
1  Notification  03758739-75a9-5462-8361-dcf5c410e015  ...                  NaN                     NaN
2  Notification  03758739-75a9-5462-8361-dcf5c410e015  ...  https://website.com                     NaN

[3 rows x 39 columns]
```